# ASP.NET Core Razor Pages OnGet of Error model not being executed

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I modified the default `Error.cshtml.cs` to log when an error gets thrown, and it worked for a while. Now after updating to .NET Core 3.0 release it's no longer working.

Here is my ErrorModel:

```cs
[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
public class ErrorModel : PageModel
{
    public string RequestId { get; set; }

    public bool ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;

        var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

        try
        {
            Logger.LogMessage(new LogMessage
            {
                RequestId = RequestId,
                Exception = exceptionHandlerPathFeature?.Error,
                Time = DateTime.Now
            });
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // ignored
        }

        return Page();
    }
}
```

And here is my Error cshtml:

```
@page "/Error"
@model ErrorModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Error";
}
<h2 class="text-danger">Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten.</h2>

@if (Model.ShowRequestId)
{
    <p>
        <strong>Anfrage ID:</strong> <code>@Model.RequestId</code>
    </p>
}

<h3>Hoppla, das sollte nicht passieren</h3>
<p>
    Bitte merken Sie sich doch den Ablauf der zu diesem Fehler führte und melden Sie ihn dem 
    verantwortlichen Entwickler somit er behoben werden kann. Bitte fügen Sie auch mindestens die ersten 8 Zeichen der Anfrage ID an
</p>
```

For reference here is my Configure Method in my Startup class

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseSession();

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapHub<FingerprintHub>("/Hub/FingerprintHub");
        endpoints.MapHub<RegistrationHub>("/Hub/RegistrationHub");
    });

    app.UseWebSockets();
}
```

The problem is that my `ShowRequestId` is always false, meaning my `RequestId` is null or empty. I put a breakpoint in my OnGet method and confirmed it's not being executed.

I also tried using a Middelware to log my Exceptions, but that didn't work either.

Anybody have an idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 reasons that `app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error")` stopped working for many of errors.

1. ExceptionHandler could invoke `Error` page either by `GET` method or `POST` method, `POST` method will be called when you `POST` a request to server and exception occurred.
2. When `POST` method is invoked from ExceptionHandler, it can't reach the `Error` page if you don't add the `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` to `PageModel`.

So you have to add `OnPost` method and attribute `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]`.

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public class ErrorModel : PageModel
{
    ...

    public ActionResult OnGet()
    {
        HandleError();
        return Page();
    }

    public ActionResult OnPost()
    {
        HandleError();
        return Page();
    }

    private void HandleError()
    {
        ...
        var exceptionHandlerPathFeature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();
        ....
    }
}
```

Enjoy it!

Answer (score 3):

I think your error is produced in a POST, PUT or DELETE, and you are trying to controlate it in the OnGet method of ErrorModel, this is executed only for errors produced in GET operations

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to  use middleware like below :

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        //if (env.IsDevelopment())
        //{
        //    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        //    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        //    app.UseHsts();
        //}

        app.Use(async (Context, next) =>
        {
            try
            {
                await next();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Context.Response.Redirect("/Error");
            }
        });

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        });
    }
```

If you want to show the error pages of the HTTP Status codes , you could call the [UseStatusCodePages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.statuscodepagesextensions.usestatuscodepages?view=aspnetcore-2.2) method before request handling middleware (for example, Static File Middleware and MVC Middleware)  in the Configuremethod of the Startup class.

Reference :

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/configuration/custom-errors

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: I stated in my question that I already tried using a Middleware and it did not work

Comment: @MindSwipe ,this is my working code , could you share a demo that can reproduce the issue ?

Comment: I just added my Startups Configure method. This should be enough to get a reproducible example

Comment: `UseExceptionHandler` should be the first middleware component added to the pipeline. The Exception Handler Middleware catches any exceptions that occur in later calls. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#order) for the order that middleware components are added in the Startup.Configure method

Comment: The Startup.cs I'm using is the default one Visual Studio generated for me when creating the new Project. The only thing I did to it was add the `UseEndpoints` and `UseWebSockets` lines. I'll try putting it at the top anyways though. Also: Funny how I just tested it in the "production" environment and it worked like a charm